# Dev tools панель инструментов устройств. При верстке Desktop ширина 1920 масштаб всегда 75%. При изменении масштаба на 100% меняется значение ширины

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Не могу разобраться, при изменении масштаба на 100% меняется ширина.[[image: скриншот**]**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4lqI.png)

Comment: Да, меняется, а какой у вас вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос какие параметры крутить что-бы, при ширине 1920px установить масштаб 100%.